# Moving array element from html table to another array in the form of an HTML unordered list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

When I click on a table row containing an array element, I want that element to move into another array, which displays as an unordered list.  The following code is working for moving array elements displayed as an unordered list to another array displayed as an unordered list but when I use it to move a table row element, the array element brings with it, `<td></td>`.  For example, if my appts array is ["Bob", "Joe", "Sally"] and I click on "Bob" to move him to patientsRoomOne [], he is added as `"<td>Bob</td>"`.

I believe that this is also causing the splice portion of my function to remove elements incorrectly as well.  Currently, if I select "Joe" to move to the patientsRoomOne array, the text is moved and displays correctly in Room One, but appts still displays "Joe" and instead removes "Bob."

Any advice the stackoverflow community can give is much appreciated!  Coding newbie here...

```
$('#apptsRoomOne').click(function()
{
    let clickedOneAppts=$('.apptsClicked').toArray();
    for (i = 0; i< clickedOneAppts.length; i++) 
    {
        patientsRoomOne.push(clickedOneAppts[i].innerHTML);
        appts.splice(clickedOneAppts[i].innerHTML, 1);
    }
        one.innerHTML = '<ul>' + patientsRoomOne.map(function (patient) {
            return '<li>' + patient+ '</li>';
        }).join('') + '</ul>';

        apptLine.innerHTML='<table>' + appts.map(function (patient) {
            return '<tr class= "appts" id="appts">' +'<td>'+ patient+ '</td>'+'</tr>';
        }).join('') + '</table>';
```

Comment: Instead of `innerHTML` in your for loop, have you tried `innerText`?

Comment: It would be alot easier to help if you also posted your HTML, and the rest of your script.

Comment: innerText worked for removing the <td> elements!  Thank you @devlincarnate! Now I just need to figure out why splice still isn't removing the correct element from the array...

Answer (score 0):

If you structure your HTML like this:

```
<ul id='mylist'>
</ul>

<table id='mytable'>
<thead><th>Name</th></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Bob</td></tr>
<tr><td>Joe</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sally</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Then your jquery code could be as simple as this:

```
const tableId="mytable";
const listId="mylist";
const $mylist = document.getElementById(listId); // vanilla JavaScript

$(`#${tableName} tbody tr`).click(function (e){
  const content = this.innerText; // vanilla JavaScript
  $($mylist).append(`<li>${content}</li>`);
  $(this).unset(); // refers to the <tr> that was clicked
});
```